# Does asynchronous file appending in Windows preserve order?

Tags: winapi, io, io-completion-ports

I call `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and then call many `WriteFile` with `OVERLAPPED` structures with both `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` members set to `0xFFFFFFFF` to append new data to file.

Is it guaranteed that operations will be completed in same order as requested?

It seem logical for me but I see no explicit and non-ambiguous proofs of that.

Quote from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156932 tells that operation is going to be synchronous:

> On Windows NT, any write operation to a file that extends its length will be synchronous.

Great. Synchronous operation preserves order. But then:

> The `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag has the most effect on the behavior of the file system for asynchronous operation. This is the best way to guarantee that I/O requests are actually asynchronous.

Latter raised doubts in me. Could someone clarify this please?

Comment: Hmm, that's rather backwards.  The lazy *disk* writes you get from using buffering are extraordinarily hard to beat for both convenience and perceived file write speed.  And the punishing slow writes you get by not using buffering are very hard to hide.  You can't see this until you try it.  If you want to do this anyway then the KB article tells you that you have to extend the file size first.  So of course that means that you must specify the position.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry but now I'm even more confused... All I want is to preserve order of writing to disk. I managed to achieve desired performance only with `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`. So if there are several operations requested, is it unknown which one will be completed next? (Currently disk writes are overlapped, maybe making them synchronous won't lead to sensible performance loss.)

Comment: Can you point to documentation that says you're allowed to set `Offset` and `OffsetHigh` to `0xFFFFFFFF` in order to append to the file?

Comment: @HarryJohnston https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx, lpOverlapped param description.

Comment: OK, thanks.  My recommendation is to not depend on that working properly for asynchronous I/O, since it doesn't mention it explicitly.  It's so easy to keep track of the EOF yourself that IMO the shortcut just isn't worth the uncertainty.  (The most likely failure mode IMO would be two consecutively issued writes both being written to the same offset.)  The article you reference is very old.  I wouldn't rely on the fine detail still being entirely correct.

Comment: See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160205-00/?p=92981